# How to continuously capture & save .jpg image frames DURING real time video stream?

Tags: javascript, python, video, google-colaboratory, mozilla

Goal: I want to continuously capture & save .jpg image frames DURING real time video stream in Google Colab. I know how to convert the saved recorded video to `.jpg` image frames. I do not want that. I want to continuously capture & save `.jpg` image frames DURING real time video stream.

Current Code: I can successfully start, record, and save a real time video stream in Google Colab.

Thank you in advance for any help.

```
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
from google.colab.output import eval_js
from base64 import b64decode

def record_video(filename='video.mp4'):

  # This function uses the take_photo() function provided by the Colab team as a  
  # starting point, along with a bunch of stuff from Stack overflow, and some sample code 
  # from: https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API

  js = Javascript("""
    async function recordVideo() {
      const options = { mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=vp9" };
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      const capture = document.createElement('button');
      const stopCapture = document.createElement("button");
      capture.textContent = "Start Recording";
      capture.style.background = "green";
      capture.style.color = "white";

      stopCapture.textContent = "Stop Recording";
      stopCapture.style.background = "red";
      stopCapture.style.color = "white";
      div.appendChild(capture);

      const video = document.createElement('video');
      const recordingVid = document.createElement("video");
      video.style.display = 'block';

      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
      let recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
      document.body.appendChild(div);
      div.appendChild(video);
      video.srcObject = stream;
      await video.play();

      // Resize the output to fit the video element.
      google.colab.output.setIframeHeight(document.documentElement.scrollHeight, true);

      await new Promise((resolve) => {
        capture.onclick = resolve;
      });
      recorder.start();
      capture.replaceWith(stopCapture);
      /*Want to convert and save video stream to .jpg image frames continuously in real time, until stop is clicked.
      Trying to access video that has been recorded to this point before stop is clicked. 
      while{
      Blob realTime = recorder.requestData();
      print("BLOB")
      }
      https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/requestData
      */
      await new Promise((resolve) => stopCapture.onclick = resolve);
      recorder.stop();

      let recData = await new Promise((resolve) => recorder.ondataavailable = resolve);
      let arrBuff = await recData.data.arrayBuffer();
      stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
      div.remove();

      let binaryString = "";
      let bytes = new Uint8Array(arrBuff);
      bytes.forEach((byte) => {
        binaryString += String.fromCharCode(byte);
      })
      return btoa(binaryString);
    }
    """)
  try:
    display(js)
    data = eval_js('recordVideo({})')
    binary = b64decode(data)
    with open(filename, "wb") as video_file:
      video_file.write(binary)
    print(
        f"Finished recording video. Saved binary under filename in current working directory: {filename}"
    )
  except Exception as err:
      # In case any exceptions arise
      print(str(err))
  return filename

# Run the function, get the video path as saved in your notebook, and play it back here.
from IPython.display import HTML
from base64 import b64encode

video_width = 300

video_path = record_video()
video_file = open(video_path, "r+b").read()

video_url = f"data:video/mp4;base64,{b64encode(video_file).decode()}"
HTML(f"""<video width={video_width} controls><source src="{video_url}"></video>""")
```